# asp .net 4.0 membership error

Tags: asp.net, membership

Please help me for this issue.

I have used asp .net membership. while creating new user using asp .net membership using below code. i am getting membership provoder error. can anyone tell me the solution for 
this.

```
    MembershipCreateStatus status;

    //MembershipUser u = Membership.CreateUser(username, password, email, question,
    //                                         answer, true, out status);

    MembershipUser u = Membership.CreateUser(username, password, email, question,
                                     answer, true, out status);


    if (u == null)
    {
        throw new MembershipCreateUserException(GetErrorMessage(status));
    }

    return u;
```

### i have properly set web.config file. please tell me if i am missing anything. here is my web.config file membeship tag. and my database is mysql :

```
    add name="MySQLMembershipProvider" 
         enablePasswordRetrieval="true" 
         autogenerateschema="false" 
         type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.3.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" 
         connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" 
         applicationName="/" 
         enablePasswordReset="true" 
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
         requiresUniqueEmail="true" 
         passwordFormat="Clear" 
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
         minRequiredPasswordLength="7" 
         minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" 
         passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
         passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" 
         writeExceptionsToEventLog="false"
```

This is my error :MembershipCreateStatus.ProviderError

Comment: your question is a little vague and you will not have that many answers, please add more information, like your `web.config` settings, if you have all tables in database, and specially, what is the Exception Error and Stacktrace.

Comment: Could you add a stacktrace please?

Comment: Is your provider properly configured?  Can you try to use the ASP.Net Configuration tool (Project -> ASP.Net Configuration) to add new users from the web admin, and let us know if you can do it or not?

Answer (score 0):

```
MembershipCreateStatus status; 

Membership.CreateUser(username, password, email, question, 
                                 answer, true, out status); 


if (status == MembershipCreateStatus.Success) 
{ 
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false);
    // Redirect to page
} 
else
{
   //get the error message here
   return ErrorCodeToString(createStatus);
}
// if you get to here, throw an exception!


private static string ErrorCodeToString(MembershipCreateStatus createStatus)
    {
        // See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=177550 for
        // a full list of status codes.
        switch (createStatus)
        {
            case MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateUserName:
                return "User name already exists. Please enter a different user name.";
```

//add the rest of the error codes here....